# How to set custom web console name in IBM WebSphere 7.0 using jython?

Tags: websphere

This is my first question,need your help,thanks!

My question is :How to set custom web console name in  IBM WebSphere 7.0 using jython?I've known how to set it on the web console.

---

this url  tells how to set on the web console and some description about custom console name string:     https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/zh/SSAW57_7.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.iseries.doc/info/iseriesnd/isc/console_id.html

---

I just want to set it(the value of  "ISC.CONSOLE.ID.CUSTOM" which key mentioned in above url) in command line(wsadmin.sh) by jython.I've search for this answer for several days，and I've also viewed the ibm official online doc.But not got what I want.
   AdminConfig,AdminTask,AdminControl,AdminApp,which type command should I use? I've read help() method of them,but also found no answer.

Please help me,thanks!

[just change the red marked title using jython](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4r39N.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please have a look at the [guidelines for asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Thanks,you're so kind!I've view the help center and improved my question.I'hope it seems like better than before.( ^_^ )